# GnuPG key validity

Tags: gnupg

I have been struggling whole day trying to understand key validity.

1. I had a public key in my pubring with *validity unknown* and *trust
   unknown*
2. I signed it with an *ultimately* trusted key and the validity became *full* trust was still *unknown*
3. then I deleted my
   signature using *minimize* command from *--edit-key* submenu
4. after that I run  *--list-keys --list-options show-uid-validity*
5. but the validity of that key was still *full* even though it was no longer signed.

Please help me to understand this mystery.

Also, please confirm if using the using command *--list-keys --with-colons nida*
gives me the same information as --list-options show-uid-validity
except for here instead of the word "full" I just get one letter "f", and instead of "ultimate", I just get "u"

Thank you in advance for helping me understand this very difficult subject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I signed it with an ultimately trusted key and the validity became full trust was still unknown

Trust is set manually and is a different thing from validity. Signing influences validity, while commands like `gpg --update-trustdb` or `gpg --edit-key $KEYID trust` will let you change the trust level.

- **Validity** describes whether this key **is the correct key**.
- **Trust** describes whether this key can **grant validity to other keys** by signing them.

Keys that you sign are automatically valid. However, keys that are signed by someone's key whom you *fully trust* are also valid. Keys are also valid if they are signed by 3 people whom you *marginally* trust.

(Practical example: [Arch Linux master keys](https://www.archlinux.org/master-keys/), where the 'owner' key grants marginal trust to 5 'master' keys, and their marginal signatures add up to validate all 'developer' keys.)

Importantly, a key can be valid *and* untrusted, and that's a completely normal situation. In fact, *most* keys that you sign or lsign should remain untrusted unless you know the *person* behind that key and (literally) trust them to validate other people's keys.

> then I deleted my signature using minimize command from --edit-key submenu

Did you use the `save` command afterwards? If not, then all your changes were lost. (The only exception is trust level changes, which don't actually change the key but get saved in the trustdb instead.)